# Visual Studio solution - issue with referenced projects and object accesibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio, structure

this might be a bit dummy question but I'm confused...
I have a simple C# solution in VS with 3 projects

- UI
- CORE
- DAL

Now, I've added '**DAL**' as a reference inside '**CORE**' so now I can see and use my DB methods.
However, since I want to send one of the '**CORE**' classes to my INSERT method which is inside '**DAL**' (to insert the full object) I cannot see or access it, and I also can't add a circular reference and add '**CORE**' to '**DAL**'.

```
public void InsertOrUpdateResultData(MyObject _obj)
```

MyObject is from '**CORE**' project.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the common classes inside a separate project and reference it from the **CORE** and **DAL**. Eventually you can create [DTOs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter such situation you are probably doing something wrong. I would suggest to rethink structure of your solution. Maybe it would be worth to create another library that can be included in both CORE and DAL projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same class across multiple projects, as is your case here.. have you thought about using a shared project?  You can add the shared project to all other projects you need.  Based on what you've stated, it would probably be a better solution.

http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/07/28/using-shared-project-across-multiple-applications-in-visual-studio-2015/